# How can I migrate users from DotNetNuke 4.9 to 7?

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke

I have a DotNetNuke 7 website that I have developed and an older version that was made in 4.9. I have to find a way to migrate the users into the new database so that the users of the website do not have to change their passwords or be inconvenienced in any fashion.

I have attempted to use plugins for this, but I cannot find one that exports 4.9 (seeing as 4.9 is so old) and another to import that file into 7.

If I try to go the manual migration route, what records would I need to pull over? I have noticed there are various user related tables. Are all of these mandatory for migrating users?

Thank you for your time. I'm just trying to understand how to go about the migration and would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the database but you have a number of tables that you have to move across and you have Integer Based ID's that you have to worry about.  Some of the tables to be aware of are aspnet_membership, aspnet_users, Users, UserProfile, ProfilePropertyDefinition, UserRoles, UserPortals and then there can be more as well.

DataSprings has a module called Interactive User Import which can also do an export.  It works great and you can get a version that works that far back.

The other thing that you have to worry about if going truly the DB route is that passwords are encrypted, as such, if you move the passwords manually you have to keep the same encryption key.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw that module but was trying to find an alternative as it is $150 for something I would use one time.

I've noticed that also have a Bulk User Manager module that is $30, it appears to have user importing and exporting. Would this module be good enough compared to the Interactive User Import module?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you don't want to risk it with user data and migration.  I know that Interactive User Import works, and that is all I can comment on.  Yes, it is $150, but that is a heck of a lot cheaper than writing your own scripts to do it!